# How to import a module from a package in Python

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python und programming in general and have a bit of a problem with packages.

I made a directory called *Package_Test* and created a file named *Test* package in it called *FUNCTIONS*.

This package contains the **init** file and a file *add*. *add* contains a function, also called *add* that returns the sum of two given numbers.

The directory tree looks as follows:

> Package_Test
>
> > Test
> >
> > FUNCTIONS
> >
> > > > > > **init**
> > > > > >
> > > > > > add

I want to use the *add* function from the package in the file *Test* and tried the code below, but always get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/CLRS_Codes/PACKAGE_TEST/Test.py", line 1, in 
>       import FUNCTIONS   File "D:\CLRS_Codes\PACKAGE_TEST\FUNCTIONS__init__.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from add import add ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'add'

In the add file I wrote:

```
def add(x, y):

    return x + y
```

In the **init** file I wrote:

```
from add import add
```

In the Test-file I wrote:

```
import FUNCTIONS

print(add(4,2))
```

I attached a picture to make the whole thing clearer.

I would be deeply thankful for any help.

[The Test-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elV1s.jpg)

Comment: `from FUNCTIONS.add import add` I think

Comment: You could save a lot of typing by just showing a tree of you file structure.

Comment: I tried this now and it works, but only if i delete the line "from add import add" out of __init__. But I read somewhere, that by writing something in  the __init__ file the long import lines may be skipped, is this true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, empty the __init__.py file.

Then in the Test.py change "import FUNCTIONS" to either:

1. import FUNCTIONS.add

   - This'll mean you need to call any function from that file as "FUNCTIONS.add.function_name(arguments)"
   - eg the add function in your example will be called through "FUNCTIONS.add.add(number1, number2)"
2. from FUNCTIONS.add import *

   - This'll allow you to call any functions from that file as "function_name(arguments)
   - eg the add function in your example will be called through "add(number1, number2)"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `import FUNCTIONS.add.add as add` or `from FUNCTIONS.add import add`. Both of these methods allow you to reference the `add` function by it's full name each time.